# Format a number to 8 or 16 chars without "e" with highest precision

Tags: python, formatting, numbers, rounding, precision

I have the following python procedure.
Input is any number (from a calculation) and format, where format can be 'long' or 'short'

What i want to do:
If the format is short, i want the output to be the number inputted but using a maximum of 8 chars (including sign). If the format is long, the output may use up to 16 chars.
Only negative numbers must have a '-' in front. Scientific format must only be used in the result if it increases the numeric precision of the "shortened" number.
If scientific number is outputted, the "e" must not be used as it uses unnecessary space:

My proc has been extended several times and does not meet the requirements in all cases.

Can anyone help me to achieve the required output in a good way?

```
def format_nastran(number, format):
if format == "free":
    return number
if format == "short":
    fieldsize = 8
if format == "long":
    fieldsize = 16

charsfor_comma = 1

# Help functions ##########################################################
def remove_trailing_zeros(number):
    # Convert to string, strip trailing zeros, and convert back to number
    stripped_number = str(number).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if '.' in str(number) else str(number)
    return type(number)(stripped_number)

def count_decimals(number):
    # Convert to string
    number_str = str(number)

    # Check if the string contains a decimal point
    if '.' in number_str:
        # Get the portion after the decimal point and count its length
        decimal_part = number_str.split('.')[1]
        return len(decimal_part)
    else:
        return 0  # No decimals


# #########################################################################


scientific = str(number).find("e")

# Case 1 Integer which fits into the field without any changes
# short format: 12345678
# short format: -1234567
# long format : 1234567812345678
# long format : -123456781234567
if scientific == -1:
    number = remove_trailing_zeros(number)
    num_chars = len(str(number))
    if num_chars <= fieldsize:
        return number
# Case 2 Integer which is to large to fit into the field, has to be converted to scientific format
# short format: 1234567891
# short format: -123456789
# long format : 123456781234567812345678
# long format : -12345678123456781234567
    if num_chars > fieldsize:
        e_number = "{:.12e}".format(float(number))
        # Split the number into mantissa and exponent
        mantissa, exponent = e_number.split("e")
        # Strip leading zeros from exponent
        exponent = int(exponent)
        if int(exponent) > 0:
            exponent = "+" + str(exponent)
        charsinexponent = len(str(exponent))
        # determine the length of the mantissa
        mantissa = remove_trailing_zeros(mantissa)
        charsmantissa = len(str(mantissa))
        # determine number of decimals
        charsdezimals = count_decimals(mantissa)
        # determine number of chars before dezimals
        chars_intpart = charsmantissa - charsdezimals - charsfor_comma
        # To how many numbers do weh have  to round the mantissa so that mantissa plus exponent fits into the field?
        round_to = fieldsize - chars_intpart - charsfor_comma - charsinexponent
        if round_to > 0:
            rounded_mantissa = round(float(mantissa),round_to)
            # assemble the whole number
            formatted_number = str(rounded_mantissa) + str(exponent)
        else:
            formatted_number = str(mantissa) + str(exponent)

        return formatted_number




if scientific != -1:
# Case 3 Scientific number which fits into the field without an changes after the 'e' and unneccesary leading 0 of the exponent has been removed
# short format: 1.2345e-005  -> 1.2345-5     3 signs gain
# short format: -1.234e-005  -> -1.234-5
# long format :
# long format :
    mantissa, exponent = str(number).split("e")
    # Strip leading zeros from exponent
    exponent = int(exponent)
    if int(exponent) > 0:
        exponent = "+" + str(exponent)
    charsinexponent = len(str(exponent))
    # determine the length of the mantissa
    mantissa = remove_trailing_zeros(mantissa)
    charsmantissa = len(str(mantissa))
    # determine number of decimals
    charsdezimals = count_decimals(mantissa)
    # determine number of chars before dezimals
    chars_intpart = charsmantissa - charsdezimals - charsfor_comma
    # To how many numbers do we have  to round the mantissa so that mantissa plus exponent fits into the field?
    round_to = fieldsize - chars_intpart - charsfor_comma - charsinexponent
    if round_to > 0:
        rounded_mantissa = round(float(mantissa),round_to)
        # assemble the whole number
        formatted_number = str(rounded_mantissa) + str(exponent)
    else:
        formatted_number = str(mantissa) + str(exponent)

    return formatted_number
```

Testdata:

```
#number = 30000000000000.0
#number = 123456789123456789
#number = -123456789123456789
#number = 12345678
number = -12345678  # The question here is if it not better to simply round instead of switching to scientific format...
#number = 6.5678e-06
#number = 6.5678999e-06
#number = 6.5678123456789123e-000006
#number = 6.5678123456789123e-000006
#number = 6.5678123456789123e+000006
#number = -6.5678123456789123e-06
#format = 'long'
format = 'short'
result = format_nastran(number, format)
print(str(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Python's format specification mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

The function looks like this:

```py
def format_custom(number: int | float, format_: str) -> str:
    if format_ == "short":
        max_length = 8
    elif format_ == "long":
        max_length = 16
    else:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Unrecognized format : '{format_}'")

    # Space used for the mantissa, period, exponent sign, exponent and optional negative sign
    used_space = 4 + (number < 0)

    return f"{number:-.{max_length - used_space}g}".replace("e", "")
```

And I tested it on a few inputs:

```py
print(format_custom(123456789, "short"))
print(format_custom(123456789, "long"))
print(format_custom(-123456789, "short"))
print(format_custom(-123456789, "long"))
print(format_custom(123456789123456789, "short"))
print(format_custom(123456789123456789, "long"))
print(format_custom(-123456789123456789, "short"))
print(format_custom(-123456789123456789, "long"))
```

### How does it work?

Most of the logic happens in the f string `f"{number:-.{max_length - used_space}g}"`

The `-` sign means that a minus sign should be used if our number is negative.

Honestly I can't find what the `.` does but it doesn't work without it. If someone could chime in and explain that would be great.

The number computed by `{max_length - used_space}` is the number of character our result is allowed to take. `used_space` is the number of spaces used by the mantissa, the period, the exponent sign, the exponent itself, and the optional negative sign.

`g` means that it should not use scientific notation if the number already matches our length criterion.

I couldn't find a way to not get the `e` symbol with the formatting language, so I just remove it from the string afterwards.

---

If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: That looks very compact and almost perfect. If i enter 4.388827777777777 and short format I get 4.389 which does not use the 8 possible chars fully. And if i input 6.5678999e-06 the answer is 6.568-06 where the 0 uses extra space which could be used to get more precision.

Comment: Could you please explain this part: (1 * number < 0) ? I do not understand the way it works.

Comment: Explanation for (1 * number < 0): number < 0 is True or False. In Python True or False are interpreted as 1 and 0, so you can use them in an arithmetic expression. (1 * number < 0) is equal to one when the number is negative, and 0 when it is positive. Indeed, if the number is negative we need one more space for the minus (-) sign.
I also just realized that the "1 *" is not needed, it is equivalent to (number < 0).
I'll edit my post to reflect this

Comment: Unfortunatly I do not know how to fix the issues you mentioned.